# Porque minhas requisições não funcionam?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring

Estou com um sistema com API - Spring e GUI - Angular. O spring tem security. O problema é: quando eu autentico, envio o JWT pra localstorage(eu sei q não é uma prática boa mas estou aprendendo sobre o assunto e etc), autentico e tudo mais porém o navegador não reconhece que eu to logado e não tenho nenhuma permissão. Já dei uma olhada e APARENTEMENTE não tem nenhum problema no backend. Creio que o interceptor que tem no programa não está funcionando e as minhas requisições HTTP estão sendo realizadas sem o header (não está aparecendo o token da sessão no header)
Alguns snippets do programa:

```java
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private service: RegisterService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
    const token = this.service.getToken();
    if (token) {
      const tokenizedReq = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
      return next.handle(tokenizedReq);
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

app.config

```java
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()), 
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
};
```

no console quando tento fazer uma requisição pra api/products mesmo estando logado com um user ADMIN

```
chunk-SXIXOCJ4.js?v=22e94460:49 
 GET http://localhost:8080/api/products net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
chunk-SXIXOCJ4.js?v=22e94460:43 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: _HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/products', ok: false, …}
```

CORS do SPRING

```java
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Content-Type"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: Não analisei a fundo mas parece que a aplicação está servindo na porta tcp 4200 e sua requisição está sendo feita na porta 8080 causando a recusa na conexão.

Comment: Entendi. No caso, está errado no CORS? configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200")); aqui?

Comment: Já tentou fazer a requisição na porta tcp 4200? `http://localhost:4200/api/products` ? Caso obtenha sucesso não seria o caso de busca e solucionar conflitos em configuração de portas tcp na aplicação para ai depois  configurar o sistema como um todo para servir outra porta tcp.

Comment: Opa, consegui fazer a requisição.  O token apareceu na header.

Comment: Já que eu consegui fazer a requisição nessa porta, qual seria o próximo passo?

Comment: O próximo passo é com você. Eu na minha opinião buscaria na documentação do ngserver saber como configurar a porta tcp